# CAST hyphen (-) to Decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, type-conversion

I have to CAST '-' (Hyphen Symbol) to Decimal(8,2) in sql server.

I am creating a CTE and dumping some data into a table with some columns. For 1 Column I need to dump  '-' AS DECIMAL(8,2). How I will achieve this...

I am using

```
    SELECT CAST('-' AS DECIMAL(8,2)) Column1
```

Which is throwing Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

"I know the above query or casting cannot be done", but I need to achieve it somehow!! please help

I have couple of queries using which I am dumping a data into a physical table. Further to this, first query is the above which is creating a table with 4 columns. in col1 I need to put '-' symbol, which in other query is a decimal 'column'. Second query is inserting the data to the same physical table. there are some calculations happening during the fetching of the data from this dynamic created physical table. This is the reason, I need to convert '-' (Hyphen) into a Decimal column

Comment: What would you expect a decimal value to be for a hyphen? Perhaps if you explain what you are really trying to do we can help. Just saying you need to cast a hyphen as a decimal is like saying you need to convert an elephant into a watermelon.

Comment: "I know this cannot be done".. sounds like you solved the problem

Comment: If you know this cannot be done, why are you trying to do it?

Comment: A CTE is nothing magical. If you restated your question as "I'm dumping some data into a table with some columns", you'd end up with the same answer

Comment: @JNevill,@bluefeet: I meant for the casting that I am doing.

Comment: @billinkc: What u have said is correct but I added the CTE just to make my question more transparent.

Comment: Plain and simple...a hyphen is not numeric and therefore can't be a decimal. There is no way around it. You could convert all your data to varchar but I would not recommend doing that. Another option would be to insert a NULL instead of this bizarre hyphen requirement. Then use ISNULL(DecimalColumn, '-') when retrieving the data.

Comment: @SeanLange: You probably meant `ISNULL(CAST(DecimalColumn AS varchar(…)), '-')`.

Comment: If you need to compare a hyphen as a decimal you have an issue in your process and there is no magic workaround. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: Actually something junk was return previously and I am cleaning it up. Anyways thank you guys!!! I will do something while fetching the data, maybe Null check might work.

Answer (score 7):

What's your base problem? You have a bad mapping.

[image]

We have strings we want to make into numbers. The problem is there is no number value for `-` Therefore, you need to do something about it. The problem with your question, is that you haven't indicated what the code should do in cases of bad values.

- Do we blow up the process and stop storing data into the table? All or nothing might make sense
- Is there a sentinel value your system uses when dealing with "bad" data. Maybe -1 makes sense. This is the approach Gordon takes.
- Can we use a NULL in the place of the bad data?
- Should we just not insert those rows into our target table?

If you're using SQL Server 2012+, we have a `TRY_CAST` method that will attempt to make the data type conversion and if it cannot, then the method returns a NULL.

There is a `IsNumeric` function built into SQL Server but it's not 100% reliable (citation needed). Pair that with a `CASE` expression and that would genericise Gordon's answer.

Otherwise, you'll need to add a filter to your source query to filter out those bad rows. I ran into a [similar situation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5312/conversion-of-varchar-data-to-datetime-failing) before with dates

Comment: Here is a decent reference to the problems with IsNumeric. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC%28%29/71512/

Comment: @SeanLange unfortunately that site requires registration to be viewed. Pity.

Comment: It is free and well worth it. I agree it is stupid it requires registration to view articles. But it is a good place to learn a lot of stuff about sql server. :)

Comment: @SeanLange: I m using sql server 2008. I have updated my question. Also, the above mentioned workaround will not work for me. I am looking for something that will insert an hyphen symbol as a Decimal type. Any workaround is okay with me, I have to sync one query with another, as their are number of calculations happening inside with both the queries. Please check the updated question

Comment: Let's be clear about this @RohitJain. YOU CAN'T PUT A HYPHEN IN A DECIMAL.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you want to cast values in a column, then just use a `case` statement to check for the hyphen:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN col = '-' THEN CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(8,2)) 
             ELSE CAST(col as DECIMAL(8, 2))
        END) as column1;
```

You may need various forms of trimming, if there are spaces at the beginning or end.