# Strange CAST behaviour with INT and a single hyphen ( - )

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, int

I just answered this question: [Concate Primary Keys in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38328695/5089204)

There I encountered a strange behaviour:

```
SELECT 5 + '-' +  8
```

returns 13

```
SELECT CAST('-' AS INT)
```

returns 0, which explains the above...

But: Why is a single hyphen casted to zero implictly?

Btw: It's the same with a single + or a (multi-)blank string...

This is related [CAST hyphen (-) to Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26061216/5089204) but points to the fact, that a cast to decimal would not bring up these results...

Comment: Probably because '-' is a minus sign.

Comment: '+' has same result.

Comment: Yes, as written in the question: Same with a `+` and an empty string...

Comment: Int has a higher precedence than char, so SQL Server cast '-' to int implicitly here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx

Comment: @DenisReznik, but is this really an answer? Yes sure, there is a higher precedence. But the question is not *Why does SQL Server tries to add these values?* but rather *Why is a single - (or a single +) implicitly casteable to INT at all?*

Comment: My guess would be it's simply a side effect of the internal conversion code, because when `CAST('-5' AS INT)` is legal, then to avoid doing additional code to check if `'-'` is the only part of the conversion and invalidate that conversion, then they simply pass it through. The same goes with `+`

Comment: What about blank string? @AllanS.Hansen

Comment: It's the same reasoning `cast('   6' AS int)` is legal, so to avoid checking if only spaces they just allow the conversion to go through as space is a legal character. I do however not have any sources to back it up - it just seems like a logical 'shotcut' to optimize performance.

Comment: Yes i agree with you.   `'      +       231  '`  is 231 It works also.

Comment: Along the same train of logic; it's the same with currency symbols and money datatype: `cast('$' AS MONEY)` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm writing this as an answer because it's too long/complex for a comment - but it's based off my comments.
Also note - I DO NOT HAVE AN OFFICIAL SOURCE, so no confirmation that my logic is "what's implemented". (But it makes sense I think :))

But suppose you're writing a conversion function, that needs to perform.

So you have a string to validate - for example `CAST('-50' AS INT);`
Then take each character on its own:

```
`-` is a valid part of the conversion, so move to next character.  
`5` is a valid part of the conversion, so move to next character.  
`0` is a valid part of the conversion, so move to next character.  
Done.
```

So supposed the string  `CAST('-' AS INT);`:

```
`-` is a valid part of the conversion, so move to next character.  
Done.
```

Now - you could do an additional check to invalidate because `-` is not allowed standalone, but that would require additional code.

Similar with `+` and spaces.
As well as the same with currency and MONEY or period and money:

```
SELECT CAST('$' AS MONEY)
SELECT CAST('.' AS MONEY)
```

Both are valid characters - but in actuality only in connection with actual numbers as well. But they parse through - indicating that it's all intentional, and speed for conversion seems sensible.

Comment: As stated below @diiN_'s answer, I agree... This is not fully intuitive, especially in case like the original one, but it is - at least - rather consistent. +1 from my side! I give you the acceptance, because your comment was the first pointing in this direction.

Answer (score 5):

This has to do with negative and positive numbers. I got to this conclusion by checking `ISNUMERIC`:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('-12')  // Result: 1
SELECT ISNUMERIC('+12')  // Result: 1
SELECT ISNUMERIC('.12')  // Result: 1 (because "." can be cast to MONEY)
```

So in your case `SELECT CAST('-' AS INT)` would get a "negative 0". Even `SELECT CAST('-.' AS MONEY)` is legal.

Comment: Because `INT` type just allows full numbers. You can't use any `.` for `INT` values.

Comment: OK, I tried these `SELECT CAST('.' AS DECIMAL(10,4))` which does not work and `SELECT CAST('.' AS MONEY)` which works actually. I think you are one the right path...

Comment: @Shnugo I think `SELECT CAST('.' AS DECIMAL(10,4))` is expecting a number because you are precisely defining the destination type. `'.0'` or `'0.'` work without problems.

Comment: I agree... This is not fully intuitive, especially in case like the original one, but it is - at least - rather consistent. +1 from my side!

Answer (score 1):

In the expression

```
5 + '-'
```

`5` is a literal of type `INT` and `'-'` is a literal of type `CHAR(1)`. `+` is going to be the numeric addition operator, and not the string concatenation operator, because implicitly converting `CHAR` to `INT` [has higher priority than the other way around](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190309), which is unfortunate.

Converting `'-'` to `INT` yields `0`, because `-` and `+` are legal as number signs, and a single sign without any digits is allowed. Why? Well, because they are. To my knowledge, this isn't documented anywhere. In fact, none of the rules are. `CONVERT(MONEY, ',,,')` yields `0` because `,` is ignored entirely as a digit separator, even though they're not separating any digits here. `CONVERT(FLOAT, '+')` is illegal, so is `CONVERT(DECIMAL, '+')`, but `CONVERT(INT, '+')` is just dandy. Books Online contains only the briefest references to behavior. If you reverse engineered the code implementing these behaviors, you'd no doubt find some ancient and dubious shortcuts in the parsers that are now maintained for compatibility.

Mind you, I'm pretty sure that if the conversion code were written *today*, Microsoft would take care that it *does* produce an error (like with `FLOAT`, `DECIMAL` or most any other numeric type), because the results are needlessly surprising. But I'm equally sure that the risk of breaking code in the wild that relies on this conversion working the way it does is far too great. (Imagine all the text files out there that use `-` as a "not applicable" value that currently gets imported as 0 and would now break with an error.)

Comment: As it was pointed out by Denis Reznik due to the operator's precedence a summation of numbers will happen rather than the concatenation of strings as one might expect it. But the quesiton was *Why is a single hyphen casted to zero implicitly?* This is somehow explainable but still seems a little strange to me...

Comment: If you have a sufficiently naive parser, it's easy enough to do. Start off with 0. Check if the first character is `+` or `-`. If so, set the sign flag appropriately. Now process the rest of the string. Whoops, there is no rest, so return the result modified by the sign: 0. (The code that processes the rest of the string knows that only digits are allowed: `--` does not convert.) It would be more involved to write code that checks if we've actually processed any digits at all and error out if we haven't (not *much* more, but the only reason to track it would be to produce an error.)

Comment: You are rigtht and that is exactly the reason why I've accepted Allan's answer. The answer to the question is not why a numeric calculation takes place, but only why `SELECT CAST('-' AS INT)` returns zero... The performance related assumption of a *sufficently naive parser* seems to be correct. +1 for the *sufficently naive parser*. Made me smile...

Comment: I doubt anyone made a conscious or even implicit decision about performance in this case, for multiple reasons. One, in a database, you absolutely want results to be correct before they are fast. Two, the check would barely slow anything down when implemented correctly. Three, `'-'` is not allowed for `FLOAT`, `REAL` or `NUMERIC` (don't those need performance?) It's more that `'-'` being a valid string due to the way the code is structured was simply missed, and nobody would want to touch this code today for fear of breaking stuff. (Added a paragraph to that effect.)

Answer (score 0):

By default in such situations, SQL Server tries to cast to the type with the highest precedence among all types in the expression. Int has a higher precedence than char, so SQL Server cast `'-'` to int implicitly here. Here is [a documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) about SQL Server types precedence.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, as stated in a comment before... Try the same with `SELECT 5 + '*' +  8` and you will encounter an error...

Comment: Yes, '*' is a sign of multiplication operation, but  '+' or '-' are the signs of a number. Int variable in SQL Server can be positive or negative, which means '+' or '-'.

Comment: This is rather obvious, but still no answer. I cannot see any reason to take a single `+` or a single `-` as a number. One could discuss the empty string, but as implicit cast this goes to far... Don't you think so?